# C# Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to change a column when a cell value has changed in a row. But It is giving an exception as shown in the title. And the suggestions tell me to avoid infinite loops. I'm not using any loops through my knowledge.

Note: I have checked other questions here on stack but it doesn't seem to provide proper answers.

```
void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 1)
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = -1;
}
```

Comment: Well, you're changing the value of a cell. Now, what event do you appear to have configured to run when you change the value of a cell...?

Comment: In the [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) they modify the same `DataGridView`in this event. Probably, the problem (infinite loop) is somewhere else.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I am trying to change a value of a cell. I am not sure I understand your follow-up question though. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Well, look at your method name. I assume that's hooked up so that the method is called every time a cell value is changed. And it changes a cell value... so it gets called again, and changes the cell value... so it gets called again, etc.